# Remote desktop program that allows multiple monitor spanning

Tags: linux, windows-8, remote-access, multi-monitor

I want to be able to more easily work from home, but doing that is difficult. So I'm looking for tools that would make it easier.

Here's my setup:

At home I have:

- Desktop computer
- 3 monitors
- running Fedora 20 or Windows 7

At work I have:

- Laptop computer
- 1 external monitor and the laptop monitor
- running windows 8 with a windows 7 virtual machine (my development environment)

**What I want:** I want to be able to, from home, access my work computer and have each screen from the work computer on a separate screen at home. So that my laptop monitor would be monitor 1 at home, external work monitor would be monitor 2 at home and monitor 3 would still be my home computer.

At work, I typically have one monitor be the virtual machine (with occasionally putting other stuff on top from the host machine) and the other monitor is the host machine. What I suppose I could do is allow remote desktop on both the virtual and host machine for the main monitors, and put each on their own monitor at home... but that seems a bit clunky and inefficient, though not a bad backup.

At home I prefer to use my Linux installation, but if need be I could probably boot into windows for the duration of the work day. Are there any good pieces of software that can do this? I'd prefer cost to be `<$50` for a lifetime license, but suggest whatever you can think of

Answer (score 1):

(windows 8.1)

remote desktop -> options -> display -> Use all my monitors for the remote session

Comment: Is that for the 'host' machine? AKA Do I have to be running 8.1 at home to do that?

Comment: remote desktop is Windows application (not just 8.1), but I am not sure if RD Win7 does have the same features (probably it does)

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully doing it, with a cross-platform "**TightVNC**"
I didn't even have to do any special setup on VNC server (remote computer). I've just installed it on a multi-monitor computer. After I've connected to the multi-monitored remote computer with "**TightVNC**", It opened a remote window with a span of all monitors.

The remote multi-monitor screen doesn't fit on my one monitor local setup, so you can use a combination of zooming out and scrolling sideways.